# Identifying Partition scheme option of ALL

Tags: sql-server

Hello greetings from Notton, UK. In creating a partition scheme I see the option `ALL` that can be utilised like this

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME myRangePS1  
    AS PARTITION myRangePF1  
    ALL TO (test1fg) ;  
GO
```

After I run that script, I have got a warning message that says `...test1fg is marked for NEXT USED`. I don't know why (I would want it to be used).
And I would also like to know where `ALL` option is located in any views that I can view by the way.